# Strange node.js runtime error: XXX is not a function (But I indeed define XXX as a function~!)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I've found a special javascript coding combinations/sequences which would cause strange node.js runtime errors ("XXX is not a function", but I indeed define XXX as a function!). It does not depends on any other libraries and tools, but some simple typescript/javascript codes could cause this error. I can not understand why I got such runtime error, could anyone help me? If it corresponds to some node.js known bugs, please tell me the corresponding ticket number, so that I can know more about this. Thanks~!

(I've already all upgraded to the latest version: node.js v4.1.1, Visual studio 2015 community version, VS 2015 node.js tools 1.1.30716.01)

As a matter of fact, I'm using Visual studio 2015 community version to write some typescript codes (*.ts), and get the javascript codes (*.js) generated by VS automatically. Against that special coding sequence, Visual studio 2015 could *happily* accept it, and generate corresponding javascript codes. But when node.js runs those javascript codes, node.js would generate that strange runtime error. Hence, I think this behavior is completely related to node.js only, but not typescript.

In summary, the typescript module in VS2015 thinks this combination is a valid typescript/javascript sequence, but the generated javascript files could not be executed by node.js, and if I change just some order of the statements, it works~! Really strange.

The typescript/javascript coding combinations/sequences contains 8 simple files. I spend couple of days to narrow the problem, and found that combination is the simplest form and could not be simplified further to get the same runtime error. If I delete some parts further, the runtime error would disappear. When executing the "main.js" file, the node.js would generate the following error, but I could not get the reason why. A_function1() and A_function2() are 2 simple functions (You could see the full file contents below), and node.js could successfully find and execute A_function1(), but not A_function2().

```
c:\>node --version
v4.1.1

c:\>node main.js
c:\c.js:3
    a.A_function2();
      ^

TypeError: a.A_function2 is not a function
    at Object.C_function (c:\c.js:3:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\main.js:4:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:475:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:89:15)
Press any key to continue...
```

[image]

=========================================================================
The 8 typescript files are as follows:

main.ts

```
import d = require("./d");    // --> If I change the order of these "imports" to "c --> d --> e", the runtime error would disappear.
import e = require("./e");
import c = require("./c");

c.C_function();

d;
e;

console.log("safe!");   // --> If the execution reaches this line, every thing would be fine. If that runtime error happened, you could not see this "safe!"
```

a.ts

```
import g = require("./g");

class A {
    static A_function1() {
    }

    static A_function2() {
        var tmp = g.G_enum.G_enum_value_1;
    }
}

export = A;
```

b.ts:

```
import a = require("./a");

export function B_function() {
    a.A_function1();   // --> This line would not cause any runtime error, node.js could successfully find what A_function1() is, and execute it~!
}
```

c.ts:

```
import a = require("./a");

export function C_function() {
    a.A_function2();   // --> This line causes the runtime error, but A_function2() is really a function~!
}
```

d.ts:

```
import f = require("./f");

f.F_function;
```

e.ts:

```
import g = require("./g");

g.G_function;
```

f.ts:

```
import b = require("./b");

export function F_function() {
    b.B_function();
}
```

g.ts:

```
import c = require("./c");

export enum G_enum {
    G_enum_value_1
}

export function G_function() {
    c.C_function();
}
```

=========================================================================
The corresponding javascript files generated by VS2015 are as follows:

main.js:

```
var d = require("./d");
var e = require("./e");
var c = require("./c");
c.C_function();
d;
e;
console.log("safe!");
```

a.js:

```
var g = require("./g");
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.A_function1 = function () {
    };
    A.A_function2 = function () {
        var tmp = g.G_enum.G_enum_value_1;
    };
    return A;
})();
module.exports = A;
```

b.js:

```
var a = require("./a");
function B_function() {
    a.A_function1();
}
exports.B_function = B_function;
```

c.js:

```
var a = require("./a");
function C_function() {
    a.A_function2();
}
exports.C_function = C_function;
```

d.js:

```
var f = require("./f");
f.F_function;
```

e.js:

```
var g = require("./g");
g.G_function;
```

f.js:

```
var b = require("./b");
function F_function() {
    b.B_function();
}
exports.F_function = F_function;
```

g.js:

```
var c = require("./c");
(function (G_enum) {
    G_enum[G_enum["G_enum_value_1"] = 0] = "G_enum_value_1";
})(exports.G_enum || (exports.G_enum = {}));
var G_enum = exports.G_enum;
function G_function() {
    c.C_function();
}
exports.G_function = G_function;
```

Comment: Strange... I upload the screenshots of the console in the post, and you could see I indeed encounter this error. After seeing your comments, I try to uninstall the node.js, and re-installed the x86 & x64 version of node.js, but I encounter the very same runtime error on both version....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basarat’s answer is correct in that you have a cyclic reference but that answer isn’t really complete for your question (although, to be fair, what you are asking about is not actually very special at all; cyclic module dependencies are fairly common in certain code structures).

In your code, module `a` is exported differently than the rest of your modules. In module `a`, you export a distinct value for the module (`export = A`), whereas your other modules are simply adding functions to their default export objects (`export function C_function`). The fact that module `a` tries to export a distinct value is the key to the problem.

When a cyclical module dependency occurs in Node.js, in order to break the cycle, Node.js must define the exported value of the conflicting module as a default export object that *it* creates, even if you tried to specify an explicit export value. For modules that simply add properties to the default export object (`export function` and `export var`), this isn’t a problem. However, when you try to define a different export object (with `export =`), that object will end up being **discarded** in favour of the default export object.

In other words, `export = A` is ignored in your code because that module ends up being part of a cycle like this:

main -> d -> f -> b -> **a** -> g -> c -> **a**

When `a` is seen for the second time, the runtime has no choice but to give `c` a default export object, since otherwise it can’t resolve the dependency graph.

To fix your call, you need to either restructure your code to remove the cyclic dependency, or you need to export functions and variables that get attached to the default export object, instead of trying to export a different object you’ve created yourself (`class A`).

Comment: Hi, Snover, Thanks~! Originally, all the files has its own "class X", and "export = X;". And during my narrowing down process, I found that if I remove the "class A" in a.ts, and export those 2 functions directly, the runtime error disappears. According to your answer, I now know the reason why. ^_^ However, according to the node.js user manual provided by basarat, why this method could solve this error? I mean, according to that page, the "a" object in c.js file would be an "unfinished copy" of "a", so it should not contain whose 2 functions defined in A.

Comment: I know the answer. In "main -> d -> f -> b -> a -> g -> c -> a", when "c" file loads the "a" object, the "a" object in the "c" file would be an unfinished copy of a's default export object. However, after "b" file finishes loading the "a" object, the a's default export object now contains the 2 functions, and that's why when the "main" file continues execution, node.js could find the a.A_function2().

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly right. In this scenario, if you tried to access any member of `a` from the body of module `c`, those properties/methods would not exist yet and it would fail. Changing to `export function` only works because you give enough time for all of the module bodies to execute before trying to call `A_function2`.

Answer (score 2):

## Cyclic References

If you have a cyclic reference : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles you might be returned an object that might now not have a function associated with the module import.

Give https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#dependency-view a go, it will find any cyclic references you might have

Comment: Hi, basarat, I think you are right~! Thx. By using VS 2015 debugger, I could see that when executing at c.js:a.A_function2(), the content of the "a" object  from "var a = require("./a");" does not contain the A_function2(). That is because there is indeed a cyclic reference: c --> a --> g --> c. And in b.js:a.A_function1(), node.js could find it is because there is no cyclic reference there, and the "a" object at that time contains those functions,